# One long class or many shorter classes?

Tags: php, oop, class

In PHP, is there any performance impact on using one long class with a lot of functions in it? Or is it advisable to use many small classes and call them separately when needed?

I am a newbie in OOPS and please ignore any silliness in the question. Thanks.

Comment: This will be helpful 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959295/i-cant-create-a-clear-picture-of-implementing-oops-concepts-though-i-understand

Comment: I think that there should be a school wide vote and see what percentage we come up with. and not only that but calculate would the statistics would be before inforcinga anything. Well thats just my perspective ( :

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's advisable not to think about the performance before you have the code. From the maintainability and understandability viewpoint, of course, smaller classes, with smaller methods are superior. (see [The Single Responsibility Principle](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/srp.pdf))

When you need to optimize, you really can assemble (automatically) all your code into a single big file, and save some time on include-s.

Answer (score 7):

First, think about clean OOP design.

Very long classes with a lot of methods and properties are very difficult to understand.

A set of well-designed classes with meaningful class names, method names and variable names are very easy to understand especially when it comes to maintenance period.

Answer (score 2):

In general, people tend to make classes that are too large and complex -- this is because it's often difficult to see where the cohesion boundaries lie.   So when you're starting out and a bit unsure, it's better to err on the side of making them too small: you can always coalesce smaller classes into a larger one... it's often much harder to refactor a large class into several small ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can and should put things in the same class as long they are directly related to the logic of the class you're creating. Size of the class doesn't mean a lot if you follow the OOP concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Personally for me I would much prefer to break the classes down into smaller files based on what they are for. If that's business objects then having a 'customer.class.php' 'account.class.php' etc would be my preference.

In most of the projects on which I've worked it's been like this, then a larger 'lib' or 'common' file which includes lots of various functions which are used all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the size is not the important part to consider in a class. What's key to a class are the dependencies of the classes.

For example, a class that depends in the database should be separates in a special class, such a Repository / Dao / Dal / Persistence class.